# Solving vector formula with dot product

Tags: vectors

I have the below triangle with vectors v and w.

[image]

I've been given the following formula however I don't understand how it was derived. $|\vec{OQ}|=|v|cos\theta$ The angle is POQ.

I'm familiar with the geometric definition of the dot product but I'm not sure how to get the above with it.
$v\cdot w=|v||w|cos\theta$

Comment: $|\vec{OQ}|=|v|cos\theta$ is not derived by the dot product. It is just by trig function of right triangle. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: OQ is the adjacent to the angle $\theta$.

Comment: @KittyL oh, I see where how it is derived now. Thank you for your answer!